# Feeding a TCL scripts control window via C++ Console

Tags: c++, tcl, sensors

I got a car simulation software that allows parameter inputs via a script control window.

What I want to do is write a small C++ Application which does some calculation and starts feeding line by line  commands into the tcl script control window of the car simulator.

The idea is to use a head-tracking sensor to get the current position in the xyz - plane and then based on the data do some processing and automatically write something like:

```
>> Movie eval {dict set View(0:0) xrot 12 yrot 0 zrot 0}
```

into the script window, to adjust the current view.

Above command would translate into panning the current camera view into the 12 degree position to the right (x -direction), being 0 degrees = looking to the front.

So my question is now:
How can I tell my C++ Application to write above command into an open script control window?

Comment: I'm not convinced that you want to do exactly what you've written, based on knowledge of `dict set`, but that's not what your question is really about…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way might be to use the [`comm`](http://tcllib.sourceforge.net/doc/comm.html) package in Tcllib (the Tcl community standard library). The only real complexity is that the protocol it uses is not publicly defined (it's mostly sending commands encoded in a particular format) so you'll need some way to talk it easily.

The easiest method of talking it may be to embed a Tcl interpreter in your C++ application. Then you'll be able to load the `comm` package into the interpreter and use `comm::comm send` to do what you want (you'll also have to require the package on the other side and copy across the ID, but that should be easy enough).

```
set remoteid ???;  # Look this up with [comm::comm self] on the other side
comm::comm send $remoteid \
    dict set View(0:0) xrot 12 yrot 0 zrot 0
```

Of course, you'll need to wrap that up inside appropriate calls to `Tcl_Eval()`, having first created a local interpreter with `Tcl_CreateInterp()` after initialising the Tcl library with `Tcl_FindExecutable()`, and so on, but that's just standard embedding.